# Splitting a square root over two lines

Tags: equations

I was wondering how i would replicate something like this, having a lot of trouble trying to this using multiline[image]

This is where i'm at so far

```
\begin{multlined}
E_{\pm} = \pm t_{1} 
\sqrt{ 3 + 2\cos {\frac {\sqrt{3} k_{x} a }{2}+\frac{k_{y} a}{2} } \\
+2 \cos{ \frac{ \sqrt{3}k_{x}a}{2}-\frac{k_{y}a}{2}}+2\cos{k_{y} a}}.
\end{multlined}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `aligned`.

A few points:

1. I used `\;` to further separate the coefficient from the square root (but probably I'd use `\frac{E_{\pm}}{\pm t_1}` to make things clearer)
2. Inside `aligned` I used `\tfrac` to reduce the visual clutter.
3. `\cos` doesn't take an argument; less braces in the source.
4. You forgot a few parentheses.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[22][1-3]
\begin{equation}
\hspace{0pt}
E_{\pm} = \pm t_{1} \; \sqrt{
  \begin{aligned}
  3 & + 2\cos \Bigl(\tfrac {\sqrt{3} k_{x} a }{2}+\tfrac{k_{y} a}{2}\Bigr) \\
    & +2 \cos \Bigl(\tfrac{ \sqrt{3}k_{x}a}{2}-\tfrac{k_{y}a}{2}\Bigr) + 2\cos(k_{y}a)
  \end{aligned}
}.
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[42][1-3]

\end{document}
```

The `\hspace` tricks are because otherwise the equation number would be moved down. Try without them first: the need may arise depending on your column width.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\[
  E_{\pm} = \pm t_{1} 
  \sqrt{%
    \begin{array}{l}
      3 + 2\cos {\frac {\sqrt{3} k_{x} a }{2}+\frac{k_{y} a}{2} } \\
      {} +2 \cos{ \frac{ \sqrt{3}k_{x}a}{2}-\frac{k_{y}a}{2}}+2\cos{k_{y}
      a}
    \end{array}%
  }
\]

\end{document}
```